# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class android.support.v4.view.ViewPager

Tags: java, android-studio, xml

Buenas tardes quiero usar ViewPager pero me sale el error mencionado a continuacion.

```
 Process: com.example.sbcclub, PID: 4706
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.sbcclub/com.example.sbcclub.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3430)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3614)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:86)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2199)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:112)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7625)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:524)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:987)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v4.view.ViewPager" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.sbcclub-5qUYpHFipPLTIP2NAIhVPQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.sbcclub-5qUYpHFipPLTIP2NAIhVPQ==/lib/arm, /system/lib, /product/lib]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:801)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:874)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:835)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
    at com.example.sbcclub.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:26)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7458)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7448)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1286)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3614)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:86)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2199)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:112)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7625)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:524)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:987)
```

todo esto me sale el logcat error de mi aplicacion.

este es mi xml que estoy usando.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
>


<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/vp_tutorials"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />






<ImageView

      android:layout_width= "@dimen/dp_45"
      android:layout_height="@dimen/dp_45"
      android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dp_20"
      android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp_20"
    android:src="@drawable/carta"
      />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width= "@dimen/dp_45"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/dp_45"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dp_350"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp_20"
    android:src="@drawable/config"
    />
```

este es mi mainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


@BindView(R.id.vp_tutorials)
ViewPager vpTutorials;



private TutorialsPagerAdapter_Fashionart tutorialsPagerAdapter_Itacamba;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ButterKnife.bind(this);
    setUpViewPager();

}

/**
 * method to setup view pager
 */
private void setUpViewPager() {


    tutorialsPagerAdapter_Itacamba = new TutorialsPagerAdapter_Fashionart(getSupportFragmentManager());
    vpTutorials.setAdapter(tutorialsPagerAdapter_Itacamba);




  }

}
```

he intentado agregando el lo siguiente en el build.gradle

```
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'
```

ya que segun viendo algunos que tuvieron mi mismo error sugirieron poner esa implementacion pero aun asi a mi se me cierra la app al intentar abrirla la app osea abre pero derrepente se cierra.

este es mi adaptador que ahi estan los fragments anadidos tambien que obviamente los fragments tienen su codigo java por defecto que viene no mas no lo he tocado solo en su layout les puse imagenes para que se vean en el ViewPager.

```
public class TutorialsPagerAdapter_Fashionart extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

private int PAGE_COUNT = 3;

public TutorialsPagerAdapter_Fashionart(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return new fragment_slide_one();
        case 1:
            return new fragment_slide_two();
        case 2:
            return new fragment_slide_three();
        default:
            return new fragment_slide_one();
    }
}

@Override
public int getCount() {

    return PAGE_COUNT;
  }


}
```

agradesco su ayuda la verdad he visto varias paginas pero ninguna muchas gracias.
solo quiero esa ese ViewPager gracias.

este es mi build gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

  android {
  compileSdkVersion 29
  buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
      applicationId "com.example.sbcclub"
      minSdkVersion 21
      targetSdkVersion 29
      versionCode 1
      versionName "1.0"
      testInstrumentationRunner 
       "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android- 
      optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
      }
    }
  }

   dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.4.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
   }
```

lo edite para poder agregar el BuildGradle

Comment: Cual es la configuración de tu build.gradle, estas usando AndroidX?

Comment: holaa jorgesys edite la pregunta para q puedas verla porfa ahi puse mi codigo buildgradle gracias.

Comment: Es problema de la clase usada , revisa mi respuesta @DavidGarcia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Revisando tu configuración en realidad estas usando AndroidX, por lo tanto cambia la clase `android.support.v4.view.ViewPager` a `androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager`

```
<androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/vp_tutorials"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

y elimina la dependencia que ya no es necesaria:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'
```

ya que tienes la que es usada para AndroidX es:

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
```

Comment: lo cambie pero sale el sgt error  `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.sbcclub/com.example.sbcclub.MainActivity}:  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.setAdapter (androidx.viewpager.widget.PagerAdapter)' on a null object reference`  tambien implemente  `implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'`

Comment: eso es otro tipo de error, estas usando vpTutorials pero no esta inicializada la variable. inicializala : vpTutorials = new  ViewPager(); antes de: vpTutorials.setAdapter(tutorialsPagerAdapter_Itacamba); @DavidGarcia

Comment: funciono ya no se cierra la app pero no me muestra las imagenes :(. no se puede hacer swipe osea horizontalmente deslizar q burrera. alguna ayuda? practicamente aparece en blanco solo con las dos imagenes q tengo. ahi. y nada mas no hace nada mas. en los 3 fragments q tengo hay 3 imagenes en cada uno para que q se deslizen cuando se desliza el dedo :(.

Comment: Ok @DavidGarcia Es un poco obvio ya que no estas cargando información en tu adapter, te sugiero realices otra pregunta en el sitio para esta problematica que es diferente a la inicial,  saludos.

Comment: Recuerda marcar como solución las respuestas que solucionen el problema planteado en la pregunta, revisa [tour], saludos.